# Android Studio Java Module does not find dependencies

Tags: java, compilation

I always get problems in my Android Studio Projects when I accidentally update parts of the IDE.

Usually it is always grade which complains it can´t find build tools anymore what so ever. If anyone could give me a hint how to avoid it ( I really don't got to have the latest versions, I'd rather stick to one and avoid updates and broken projects) it would be very much appreciated.

But currently a even stranger problem occurred.

The Gradle build works but when running the code this error is thrown:

```
Error:(62, 22) Gradle: error: package com.apple.eawt does not exist
```

My build.gradle file is this.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

My JDK versions in library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines are
1.6.0 , 1.7.0 and 1.8.0

in 1.6.0 the ui.jar ist included but as soon as I change the JDK in the project structure it tells me I must use java 1.8

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

EDIT: I managed to solve it by adding jar dependency into my build path.
I had to add the UI.jar which includes the eawt classes.

Now my application is complaining that it can´t find audio resources and images. They are in the resource folder, they worked before....
Does anybody got an idea what the source of these problems is? It's all connected, the missing com.apple.eawt which I had to add again and my resource files. What causes these problems?

Comment: Gradle is the build tool and it is telling you it can't find that package. What is the content of the libs/ folder?

Comment: I wonder too :D any idea where to look for that folder?

Comment: You're importing the package `com.apple.eawt` package in your code, is this correct?

Comment: @m0skit0 yes. see the screenshot above.
I solved it, but the problems continue, now it won´t find my files in the resource folders. see the edit comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the solution myself. The jar archive which gets created by gradle was missing. I have no clue why it got lost, but after adding it again:
Module-rightclick-Module Properties-> add jar dependency-> search modulname.jar archive in module directory/build/...   and add it, it worked fine again.

[image]

[image]

[image]

In my example as shown in my project folder it would be the javalib folder (module) /build/libs/javalib.jar (modulename.jar)

Here is the official documentation for this archive file:
[image]

I guess for newer versions things changed because I can't find those archives anymore in my newer projects. Does anybody know something about this?